# Chrome browser is not using 'Open Sans' font defined in my web page instead it is using default for a website

Tags: html, css

I have included font link in my every .html file of website

and defined in CSS to use :

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

And it is working fine on firefox but in chrome, it is not picking up this font even after mentioning explicitly in my .html page.

In Chrome, we have to change font type from settings manually. So I am looking a way to force Chrome to use the font type which is mention in my website rater using its own.

Please provide me any code line and explanation to achieve this.

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        p{
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <p>This is Simple text to identify if font-family Open Sans is shown by chrome or not. This is Simple text to identify if font-family Open Sans is shown by chrome or not. This is Simple text to identify if font-family Open Sans is shown by chrome or not. This is Simple text to identify if font-family Open Sans is shown by chrome or not. This is Simple text to identify if font-family Open Sans is shown by chrome or not. This is Simple text to identify if font-family Open Sans is shown by chrome or not.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

you can also see this on [Click this link on chrome to see this live](https://boq3mbnszzo7b9hp9cwzgq-on.drv.tw/www.myweb.com/)

Comment: Open Sans is a web font, not a system font. You haven't included the web font in your page.

Answer (score 2):

welcome on Stackoverflow.

If you look the href of the stylesheet you included the Muli font, `..?family=Muli` in order to use the Open Sans you should include the it, replace it with `?family=Open+Sans`

Comment: sorry for that mistake but see this link boq3mbnszzo7b9hp9cwzgq-on.drv.tw/www.myweb.com and then view the source code. it is using Open Sans but only on chrome, it is not working when the web is live (but Open sans are shown when it is offline). with firefox, it is shown both offline and online/live website. Please see my above code I corrected the link

Comment: Hi Davebra, can you please suggest me why it not showing Open Sans when the website is live. I also corrected my link of font family to Open+sans

Answer (score 0):

Your link reference is bad i think, i have a different thing when selecting the font:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: sorry for that mistake but see this link boq3mbnszzo7b9hp9cwzgq-on.drv.tw/www.myweb.com and then view the source code. it is using Open Sans but only on chrome, it is not working when the web is live (but Open sans are shown when it is offline). with firefox, it is shown both offline and online/live website. Please see my above code I corrected the link

Comment: Hi Riven, can you please suggest me why it not showing Open Sans when the website is live. I also corrected my link of font family to Open+sans

Answer (score 0):

I have thought, The real cause is a chrome security add-on Pri*** Ba****, which I disabled and now I can see Open Sans on the live web also.